# Using addeventlistener handle another class file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, smartfoxserver

I know I can use the addEventListener method to handle one:

```
addEventListener(SFSEvent.CONNECTION, MyMethod)
```

as I would for handling a method in another class? Like...

```
addEventListener(SFSEvent.CONNECTION, Myclass.class)
```

or

```
addEventListener(SFSEvent.CONNECTION, MyClass.method)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may pass another function handler to a class

For example

```
Class A {

     public function A() {
          addEventListener(SFSEvent.CONNECTION, MyMethod);
     }

     private function _handler:Function;

     public function set handler(value:Function):void {
           _handler = value;
     }

     private function MyMethod(e:SFSEvent):void {

        if (_handler)　{
            _handler.apply(null, someParam);
        }
     }

}
```

Then pass the target handler to A instance

```
var a:A = new A();
var b:Myclass = new Myclass();
a.handler = b.someMethod;
```

If the function is a static function, You may just do it like this

```
addEventListener(SFSEvent.CONNECTION, SomeClass.aStaticFunction);
```